# Nesting Email Distribution Groups into job code Groups

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013

My company wants to create job code groups. A single group for a single job code. For example, if Bob is a courier, the only groups he will have is the "Domain User" and Courier. Couriers are part of 3 distribution groups, 1 universal and 2 global. They are also in 4 global security groups and 1 mail-enabled global security group.

Of course, no reason is given, just they want it that way.

The problem I am facing is the end user is not receiving the distribution email.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the purpose of a global distribution group?

Answer (score 1):

If there is an NDR message? Check the message tracking log towards this DG using Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients DG@domain.com.  Are all the groups you mentioned mail-enabled universal distribution or security groups? You can use Enable-DistributionGroup command to enable an existing universal group. Here’s an article for your reference. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/Enable-DistributionGroup?view=exchange-ps